# How to constrain a QRubberBand within a QLabel?

Tags: c++, qt5, qmouseevent, rubber-band

I am building a Qt5 application that allows a user to draw a rubberband with his mouse over an image, to select certain area of the image for further processing.

I got my code to only allow the user to start drawing the rubberband, by subclassing a QLabel to a custom class (frame_displayer) which **mousePressEvent()** is overridden and thus be only invoked when the mouse press happens within the custom classed widget.

The problem is that when the initial click is inside the frame_displayer, **mouseMoveEvent()**, the function that I use to change the rubberband size accordingly, keeps getting called even when the mouse cursor has been dragged outside of the frame_displayer.

I have tried using **leaveEvent()** and **enterEvent()** to control a class boolean flag that codes inside mouseMoveEvent could rely on to know whether the cursor is still within the widget. However, both **leaveEvent()** and **enterEvent()** are only called while a mouse button is not being held, thus rendering them no use for constraining the rubberband.

Also, the **underMouse()** always return true, for a reason unknown to me.

### Segment of frame_displayer.cpp

```
frame_displayer::frame_displayer(QWidget * parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
    _rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
}

void frame_displayer::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    _lastClickedBtn = event->button();
    if (_lastClickedBtn == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        _mouseOriginClickPoint = event->pos();
        _rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(_mouseOriginClickPoint, _mouseClickPoint));
        _rubberBand->show();
    }
}

void frame_displayer::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(_rubberBand != nullptr)
    {
        if (this->underMouse())
        {
            if (_lastClickedBtn == Qt::LeftButton)
            {
                QPoint mouseCurrentPoint = event->pos();
                _rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(_mouseOriginClickPoint, mouseCurrentPoint).normalized());
            }
        }
    }
}

void frame_displayer::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    _mouseOriginClickPoint = QPoint();
    _lastClickedBtn = Qt::MidButton;
    if(_rubberBand != nullptr)
    {
        _rubberBand->hide();
        _rubberBand->clearMask();
    }
}

void frame_displayer::leaveEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Leaving";
}

void frame_displayer::enterEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Entering";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's the expected behaviour.  If you want to limit the extents of the rubber band then simply clamp them in the `mouseMoveEvent` override...

```
void frame_displayer::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(_rubberBand != nullptr)
    {
        if (this->underMouse())
        {
            if (_lastClickedBtn == Qt::LeftButton)
            {
                QPoint mouseCurrentPoint = event->pos();

                /*
                 * Clamp mouseCurrentPoint to the QRect of this widget.
                 */
                auto clamp_rect = rect();
                mouseCurrentPoint.rx() = std::min(clamp_rect.right(), std::max(clamp_rect.left(), mouseCurrentPoint.x()));
                mouseCurrentPoint.ry() = std::min(clamp_rect.bottom(), std::max(clamp_rect.top(), mouseCurrentPoint.y()));
                _rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(_mouseOriginClickPoint, mouseCurrentPoint).normalized());
            }
        }
    }
}
```